# Know all Delegate Controls

Tags: 2010, delegate-control

I am wondering if there is any way to find a list all deletage controls which exist on SharePoint Root group by ControlID and Ordered by Sequence.

How does sharepoint locate the control with lowest sequence id when AllowMultipleControls is set to false?

Comment: My dev laptop isn't handy right now, but if you open up Microsoft.SharePoint.dll in ILSpy or similar, then look for Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DelegateControl.CreateChildControls() it might give you some clues there.

Comment: James, the classes which can get me there are internal. So I guess we are left with writing our own script/code.

Comment: Yeah they'll be uncallable, but at least you can see how it does it, so you can replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one way to do this would be to iterate over all the feature definitions in the Farm looking for the relevant elements defintions. I recall needing to do something like that when I needed to list all Custom Actions. As the points above state, all the info can be seen using the reflector/ILSpy and you'll need to write your own versions.